# link an image with empty spaces in the name

Tags: php, html

I have a small gallery of images where the customer can upload images and preview. I am using "lightbox" to make the jquery preview.

The script works fine with any image name except those with empty spaces (more than 1 word on it. For example "Sin titulo.jpg")

I save in the db the name of the img, and in the server the img. Both are equal and both have the blank.

What is the best way to manage spaces?

Comment: Please show the markup that fails. Are you correctly surrounding the `<img src="" />` attributes in double-quotes?

Comment: This should work normally. And please, the correct spelling is 'with'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the php version of this, but what you're after is something called encoding. It will most likely be called something like htmlEncode.

Basically it turns "Sin titulo.jpg" into "Sin%20titulo.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the names in your database so they use %20 instead of a space. This should make them work in all browsers. see [urlencode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)